# Required Modules by Translation Management Tool (tmgmt)

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

I read the description for the [translation management tool (tmgmt)](https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt) and I found it requires many other modules. I'm wondering what the modules do specifically to make the tmgmt work? I read their respective project page descriptions, but that doesn't really help me understand how exactly it integrates with the module. Those modules are:

- [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity)
- [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)
- [Chaos Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools)
- [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)
- [Content Translation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21translation%21translation.module/7)
- [Locale](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21locale%21locale.module/7)
- [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n)
- [Entity translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation)
- [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)

Is there quick explanations or examples regarding how they support tmgmt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A explanation on what these modules do

- Entity API: Provides API functions that makes working with entities easier (e.g. tokens for entity fields, CRUD functions, etc.). There's no visible functionality here.
- Views: Provides a way to select into data tables (e.g. users, nodes, etc.), filter them, and display the data in different modes (e.g. as page, block, RSS feed, etc.)
- CTools: A suite of API/utility functions to help with development tasks (e.g. creating modals, handle AJAX requests, etc.). The only visible functionality is Page Manager, a UI that allows you to override URLs paths with a different display).
- Views Bulk Operations: Adds an option to Views to select multiple items and perform an operation on them (e.g. bulk unpublishing selected nodes).
- Content Translation: A core Drupal module that enables the ability to translate node content into other languages.
- Locale: A core Drupal module that enables the ability to translate the interface (e.g. button & label names).
- Internationalization: A suite of UI tools that extends out Locale to provide more control with interface localization.
- Entity translation: Provides a UI for the Content Translation module.
- Rules: Provides UI and API for enforcing workflow. These enforcements are called Rules which has 3 parts: an *event* (something thing happened to your data), a *condition* (checks on the data to see it matches your scenario), & *action* (actions to take to enforce your workflow on your data).

There's much more to these modules than what a couple sentences can provide. Read the respective documentation pages for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much Shawn! Those are concise and great answers! I have one more follow-up question though: I know that some modules are contributed modules and some are core modules. So what are contributed modules?

Comment: They are modules separate from [Drupal core project](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal), but depend on Drupal core to operate. Each fulfills a use scenario that everyone might not need for their CMS. Sometimes these modules are so useful they become a part of core (e.g. Views in Drupal 8). The opposite can happen as well, where unused core modules are pushed out (e.g. [PHP filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/php) in Drupal 8). d.o. has a section on [contributed modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/340271) that can you learn more about their use.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers! I want to give you a vote, but my reputations are not high enough to do that. But thanks for answering! :)

Comment: No problem. You can mark this as answering the question which will give both of us rep.